# How to parse JSON data into newly created <div> elements?

Tags: javascript, json

I am new-ish to javascript, and currently trying to build a stock web page. Right now I am trying to parse JSON information and use it so that when I add a new  element through JS - that  element will be populated with certain information from the API I'm requesting from.

I think it must be due to the way I have my functions laid out, and I can currently log the JSON data to the console, but I can't get the JSON data into the new  element.

```
async function getStockData() {
  const response = await fetch(api_url);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}

function addStockWidget() {
  data = getStockData();
  var boxEle = document.createElement('div');
  var container = document.querySelector('.stockcontent');
  boxEle.style.width = '70%';
  boxEle.style.height = '50px';
  boxEle.style.border = '1px solid black';
  boxEle.style.margin = '15px 0px 0px 15px';
  boxEle.textContent = data;
  container.appendChild(boxEle);
}
```

In the second part of the code, the  variable is something I was just messing with and I have no idea if that is the correct way to go about this. Same for the `.textContent` on the `boxEle` object.

Comment: Use a `pre` element instead of a `div`  to display JSON, and `JSON.stringify(data)` the JSON object you display in the pre element.

Comment: You're just trying to set the whole data object as the text content, that won't work - it has no inherent visual representation. If you want to get a certain value from the data, then write code which references the specific property which contains it. We don't know the structure of this data (you didn't share the JSON) or exaftly what you need from it so we can't give specific advice.

Comment: `data = getStockData();` <--- there is no await

Comment: Anytime you have an `async` function, you must `await` it. `
var data = await getStockData();` and `async function addStockWidget()`.
We will need to see the api response before we can help you to add it to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use helper function that use API data.
- For example, here I have used `jasonplaceholder` API, for fake data.
- We are fetching data and providing it to helper function `addStockWidget(data)`.

```js
async function getStockData() {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/');
  const data = await response.json();
  data.forEach(val => {
    // ptoviding received api data to function and accessing it inside that function.
    addStockWidget(val);
  })
}

function addStockWidget(data) {
  //using data in function
  console.log(data.title);
}
// calling function to load api data
getStockData();
```